# Predict likelihood of each failure type with competing risks model in R

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

I'm looking to run a competing risks model on historical data and predict the likelihood of each type of death in a new dataset for a specified period (let's say one period). So far I've looked into `comp.risk` in the `timereg` package and `crr` in `cmprsk`, but am having trouble figuring out how to use their predict methods to return these likelihoods.

Using the `bmt` dataset (from `timereg` package) and `comp.risk` as an example, I'd like to do something like:

```
m <- comp.risk(Surv(time, cause>0)~platelet+age+tcell, data=bmt,
               bmt$cause, causeS=1, resample.iid=1)
ndata <- data.frame(platelet=c(1,0,0), age=c(0,1,0), tcell=c(0,0,1), 
                    start.time=c(1, 1, 1), end.time=c(2, 2, 2))
out <- predict(m, newdata=ndata)
```

This would ideally predict the likelihood of each type of death between `t=1` and `t=2`, but the predict function returns other types of results.

The final line won't work because the model wasn't built with the start/stop `Survival` object type and `comp.risk` doesn't seem to take left-truncated data. To illustrate, the below model statement including start times returns the error *Error in `comp.risk(Surv(start.time, time, cause > 0) ~ platelet + age +`  : 
  only right censored data*.

```
m <- comp.risk(Surv(rep(0, nrow(bmt)), time, cause>0)~platelet+age+tcell, data=bmt,
               bmt$cause, causeS=1, resample.iid=1)
```